# Can't see row numbers with large font

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-datatable, browser

I am using Salesforce's lightning-datable with show-row-number-column .
When customer uses large font in Chrome, row numbers cannot be seen(see ... instead) :
[image]

HTML:

```
<lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={tableColumns}

                column-widths-mode="auto"
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                default-sort-direction={dataTableSorting.defaultSortDirection}
                sorted-direction={dataTableSorting.sortDirection}
                sorted-by={dataTableSorting.sortedBy}
                onsort={onHandleSort}
                show-row-number-column="0"
                min-column-width="100"  
                hide-checkbox-column>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

Ideas?

Comment: probably due to the width of the col, have you tried adjusting it? you should probably change the column-widths-mode

Comment: it is fixed and cannot be changed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation